# Slip or no slip at liquid-liquid interfaces

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, liquid-state

Suppose I have two liquids (oil and water). Which condition is more realistic at the interface of the two liquids: Slip or no slip and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is correct.  The correct condition is that the shear stress is continuous across the interface.

Comment: Why is the shear stress continuous across the interface?

Comment: Because the interface is massless, so the traction stresses on both sides of the interface must be equal and in equilibrium.